# How to use passport-google-oauth20 with a SPA react application?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, google-oauth

How do I trigger the Google Sign In authorization  window to popup?

I'm using JaredHanons' "passport-google-oauth20" library to help with authentication on an application in combination with JSON WebTokens.

My frontend is a single page application with react. I currently have a node.js/express.js api backend and, right now, a separate frontend dev server with react. Frontend wise I have a login button calling:

`axios.get("http://localhost:3000/oauth/google/getToken/")`

Which is hitting:

```
`app.get(
  "/oauth/google/getToken",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile"]
  })
);`
```

After it hits the api end point is sends a response with a data value with the RAW Google HTML!
`{
    data: "<!DOCTYPE html...";
    status: 200;
}`

If type api endpoint in the browser url bar localhost:8080/oauth/google/getToken it loads the raw GoogleSignIn window like I want it to. Is there anyway to redirect to this page on the frontend instead of getting raw html?

Comment: Nick - Do you mean popup a window using something like `window.open(...)` to authenticate with Google?

Comment: check the docs for the library you are using. It may be that instead of `axios.get` that URL, you should be redirecting your browser to it.